# Is it feasible/possible to have encrypted data that looks unencrypted/innocuous?

Tags: encryption

i.e., could I send "Let's rob the store at 9 tonight" so that it is impossible to see what I'm saying, but it doesn't look like gibberish and obviously encrypted?

Comment: [Format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). This may be better suited at Crypto.SE as it is about an encryption scheme and not risk-management, malware or related things.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess what you want is actually [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

The drawbacks of this approach includes:

- Some kind of shared secrete is needed between the sender and the receiver;
- The "encrypted data" will be much bigger than the secret message itself.

Answer (score 1):

Steganography does exactly that! 
You can hide text inside a file(image/audio/video). One way is to work with images. You can manipulate the pixels of the image to store the text message. The difference is not visible to the naked eye, and one cannot tell apart the original image from the image having encrypted text. The size of the image remains constant, in most of the cases.
But the receiver should know that the received file has some encrypted matter in it, so that he/she can apply appropriate program/algorithm to extract the encrypted matter from the file.

Comment: In theory, steganography does this.  In practice, it breaks down because the message being hidden rarely has the same statistical properties as the file it's being hidden in.

Comment: Can be text within text too. Seehttp://www.spammimic.com/explain.shtml